# Excel 2016 Pivot Table Column rename

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, rename

I have a pivot table with total dollars in the value, year in the columns (2017 and 2018), rows by product.  I add the totaldollars field again, and change it to difference from prior year from the Value Field Settings, Show Values As tab.  Excel shows in the pivot table another two columns with 2017 and 2018. When I try to change this name to Difference, it changes the original columns as well.  Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: When I try to change this name to Difference, it changes the original columns as well. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: That is basically what I am encountering.  I have columns that are 2017 and 2018, using payment in values.  When I add the payment one more time and change it to difference, it changes my other columns.  Looking to figure out how to fix this,